# mysql date comparision is not working unable to find the issue

Tags: mysql, date, string-to-datetime

i have a huge data with dates as string.

column name `date1`

datatype `varchar`

the stored data is in this format:**14-Mar-2016 05:44:38pm**

Now I have split only date from this string like this: **14-03-2016**

By using this: `DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(gr.date1, '%d-%M-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y')`

Now I am trying to compare the date with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT date1,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date1, '%d-%M-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') as dateFormatted
 FROM `grabt` ) as mTbl WHERE mTbl.dateFormatted >= '19-01-2016' 
 AND mTbl.dateFormatted <= '25-01-2016'
```

but it is not working what could be the possible error.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp string `14-Mar-2016 05:44:38pm` can be converted to a datetime using the `STR_TO_DATE()` along with the format string `%d-%b-%Y %r`.  We can then obtain only the date portion by wrapping that with `DATE()`.  Have a look here [for a demo to see that this works](http://rextester.com/AKRLL81232).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date1, '%d-%b-%Y %r')) AS dateFormatted
    FROM grabt
) AS mTbl
WHERE mTbl.dateFormatted BETWEEN '2016-01-19' AND '2016-01-25'
```

As Gordon already pointed out, you should ideally be using date types not strings for your date calculations.  And by the way, use a valid date string when comparing in your `WHERE` clause.  `YYYY-MM-DD` is a valid format, e.g. `2016-01-19`, but `19-01-2016` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use the right types for columns.  Perhaps you are stuck with someone else's really bad decision to store date/times as strings.  Perhaps you cannot change that.  But, within a query, use the right types!

```
SELECT mTbl.*,
       LEFT(date1, 10) as FormattedDate  -- Is this really necessary?
FROM (SELECT date1,
             STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(date1, 10), '%d-%M-%Y') as thedate
      FROM `grabt`
     ) mTbl
WHERE mTbl.thedate >= '2016-01-19' AND
      mTbl.thedate <= '2016-01-25';
```

This will do the comparison as *dates* not as *strings*.

Comment: not `thedate` there might be issue in `%d,%M` now zero results actually results exist